# Find the non-exposed nodes in a binary tree

Tags: python

How do I find the non-exposed nodes in a binary tree. When I say non-exposed nodes, I mean that the nodes are covered from Top, Bottom, Left, Right sides in the tree.

Meanings:
When a node is non-exposed at top: it has a parent node
When a node is non-exposed at bottom: it has at least one child
When a node is non-exposed at left (or right): it has at least one node in the same horizontal level to the left (or right) of the given node

Note: The tree need not necessarily be a complete binary tree

Comment: Are you looking for the nodes that at least doesn't have one of the ( parent, left, right) nodes?

Comment: Clarified the question

Comment: What is a top and bottom in a binary tree?

Comment: Clarified the question. Top and Bottom is defined in a node, not a tree.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a breadth-first search to find all nodes by level, and then choose the nodes from levels that are not parents or leaves, and are buffered by a node to the left and right:

```
from collections import deque, defaultdict
def non_exposed(tree):
   d, q = defaultdict(list), deque([(0, tree)])
   while q:
      d[(v:=q.popleft())[0]].append(v[1])
      q.extend([*filter(lambda x:x[-1], [(v[0]+1, v[1].left), (v[0]+1, v[1].right)])])
   return [j for a, b in d.items() for j in b[1:-1] if a and any([j.left, j.right])]
```

---

Demo:

```
import random
class Tree:
   def __init__(self, v, left = None, right = None):
      self.v, self.left, self.right = v, left, right
   def __repr__(self):
      return f'Tree({self.v}, {self.left}, {self.right})'

def get_tree(n):
   v = random.randint(1, 10)
   return None if not n else Tree(v, left=get_tree(n-1), right=get_tree(n-1))

test_tree = get_tree(5)
results = [i.v for i in non_exposed(test_tree)]
print(len(results))
```

Output:

```
8
```

Explanation:

`get_tree` builds a complete "binary" tree of `n` levels. In such a tree, the total number of complete nodes will be `sum(pow(2, i) - 2 for i in range(2, n-1))`, thus giving a result of `8` when `n=5`.

Comment: Thank you! It took a while to understand the solution, but it makes sense now.

Comment: This is some very dense and hard to read code, almost as if you’re afraid of newlines. I really don’t like this perpetuating but completely false notion that one-liners are somehow indicative of developer genius.